# a wait that stops the test till nothing is happening in the web page anymore

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using *Java* and *Selenium* to write a test. Many times in my test i have to wait till the page or some part of it loads something. I want to wait till the load is finished. I found these two:

```
1) pageLoadTimeout
2) setScriptTimeout
```

But I don't know the exact difference between them or even if they are what I need.
The document says:

`setScriptTimeout: Sets the amount of time to wait for an asynchronous script to finish execution before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, then the script will be allowed to run indefinitely.`

and

`pageLoadTimeout: Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.`

but I don't really get it.

what I need is a wait that stops the test till nothing is happening in the web page anymore.

Comment: @Louis would you know the answer please?

Answer (score 3):

Define "nothing is happening in the web page." Now define it in such a way that will satisfy every web page ever created, or that ever will be created. Did your definition include that no more network traffic is coming over the wire? Did your definition include that the `onload` event has fired? How about `document.readyState` returning a value meaning "complete?" Did you take JavaScript execution into account? How about JavaScript scheduled using `window.setTimeout()`? WebSockets? Service Workers? What about `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements?

Now you know why WebDriver doesn't have a "wait for page complete" type of wait. The items mentioned above don't even begin to scratch the surface of the list of things a user could legitimately use in a definition of "nothing is happening on the page anymore." The correct approach would be to wait for the element you want to interact with on the next page to be available in the DOM. The `WebDriverWait` class is ideally suited for exactly this.

Comment: I just had an exchange with a senior QA man with 20+ years experience in a testing slack group, who wanted the same thing and I explained that's where wait strategy comes in, surprisingly he dismissed everything we said, called using waits the "dumb/lazy" way and left the slack channel.